# How to Reloading a partial view from the view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In  my ASP.NET MVC project i have the following situation:

An ExController with this action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //Get Data from Repository
   return View(Model);
}
```

In the Ex View folther i have a Index.cshtml and a _PartialIndexGrid.cshtml.

In the Index i have a ribbon menu with a checkbox, and when i click on it i would like to refresh just the grid placed on the _PartialIndex.cshtml, is it possible?

The Index View:

```
 //Ribbon Code here
  @Html.Partial("_PartialIndexGrid", Model)

 <script>
 if (e.parameter) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
                type: "get",                    
                success: function (result) {
                    $("_PartialIndexGrid").html(result);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
 </script>
```

This script actually do the ajax request, but is not reloading the grid partial view.
Thanks.

Comment: Have You wrapped `@Html.Partial("_PartialIndexGrid", Model)` in some div?

Comment: @Satpal no, its not inside a div or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container div and on checkbox change check if its checked reload the partial view via ajax call like this:

```
<div id="PartiaContainer">

 @Html.Partial("_PartialIndexGrid", Model)



</div> 

<input  type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>

<script>


$('#checkbox1').change(function(){

            if(this.checked)
            {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
                type: "get",                    
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#PartialContainer").html(result);
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
}
});
 </script>
```